# Recording audio+video from webcam with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm having a problem trying to record audio+video from my webcam to a file. If I use `videotestsrc` and `autoaudiosrc` I get everything right (read as in I get a file with audio recorded from the webcam's mic, and test-video image), but as soon as I replace `videotestsrc` with `v4l2src` (or `autovideosrc`) I get `Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video0'`.

The command I'm using:

`gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace! theoraenc ! queue ! oggmux name=mux autoaudiosrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! mux. mux. !  queue ! filesink location = test.ogg`

Why is that happening? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

In fact, something as simple as

`gst-launch-0.10 autovideosrc ! autovideosink autoaudiosrc ! autoaudiosink`

is failing with the same error `(Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video0')`

Replacing `autovideosrc` with `videotestsrc` gives me test image + real audio.

Replacing `autoauidosrc` with `audiotestsrc` gives me real image + test audio.

I'm starting to think that this is some kind of limitation of my webcam. Is that possible?

EDIT:

GST_DEBUG=2 log here: http://pastie.org/4755009

EDIT 2:

GST_DEBUG="v4l2*:5" (gstreamer 0.10): http://pastie.org/4810519

GST_DEBUG="v4l2*:5" (gstreamer 1.0): http://pastie.org/4810502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a 
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`
Does that run? If not repeat as
`GST_DEBUG="v4l2*:5" GST_DEBUG_NO_COLOR=1 gst-launch 2>debug.log ...`
and check the log for errors. You also might want to run v4l-info (install v4l-conf under debian/ubuntu) and report what formats your camera supports.

Comment: You have a small typo (```ffmpegcolorscale``` instead of ```ffmpegcolorspace```). And yes, it works, but that not the point of my question. As I said, I can get video only or audio only, but not both.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the typo. Can you get a debug.log for the faling pipleine and put it up on some pastebin site. This all sounds quite weired.

Comment: This paste is only at warning level (2) - more detail would be needed.

Comment: I can see this
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Input/output error
followed by the gstreamer warning. There seems to be some problem with your driver, it says that one can used mmap buffers, but when using them capture fails (if also audio is captured). I would see if I can find any other app that can capture audio+video here and also discuss with the driver authors in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid that the problem would be something related with either my device or my driver. Btw, I already confirmed that the code I use works as expected on another machine with another webcam.